# Launch WPF executable and set parent?

Tags: wpf, executable, setparent

I have a WPF executable and I want another program to launch it and set this launching program as the parent windows of my WPF executable (The main purpose is that when the launching program is closed the WPF executable is also shut down). I thought I could make it like this: I pass the Hwnd as one command line parameter (as integer-string), and I can call the SetParent or whatever function inside my WPF executable code to specify the parent. However, I can't make it work. Can anybody tell me how to do that, or any other way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Window handles are per-process.

Besides, you wouldn't want to. It's problematic enough to have a parent window in another *thread* -- that causes the message queues of the two threads to become attached, i.e., they effetively share the same message queue from then on. So now if *either* thread locks up, or does some lengthy processing, both threads are frozen. (And there's no way to later detach the message queues, as far as I'm aware.) Imagine trying to extend this cross-process.

If you must start some new code and use an existing window as a parent, you can't go cross-process. You would have to load the WPF code into your process and call a method in it, passing your parent window as a parameter. The simplest way to load that code into your process would be to change your WPF application to a class library (.dll), and either add a reference to that .dll, or load it dynamically using Reflection.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. As little experience as I have on interoperability, I get your whole point. But I want to ask a more technical question: if I change the .exe to .dll (so now it is in the same thread), how exactly I can set the parent? I tried Declare Function to use the Findwindow and SetParent function of Windows API, but still don't know for example, how to get the Hwnd of the executable window. Thanks!

Comment: Set the Window.Owner property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As @Joe White said you cannot achieve this straightaway ... I think I can "guess" what you are getting at ....

You probably have a WinForm MDI parent (its exe already) and you want to launch another WPF window (another exe) as its child. Am I correct?

Hmmmm then you would have to create a new `WinForm` child window with `WinFormWPFHostApp` in it and then refer the WPF assemblies to this project and try to host the `Content` of the `MainWindow` from that other WPF application.

refer [this](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=78) article...

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I guess our situation is more complicated: we have a legacy SW wirtten in MS Access. We want to switch to .Net but it must be a long way. So now we want to implement some new requirement using .Net but obviously must integrate it with our legacy MS Access software. So here comes my question.